# Rails routing trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

According to

> rake routes

i have such route

> types_model GET /types/model(.:format)        types#model

I have such method:

```
def model
  @models = Model.find(:all, :conditions => { :MOD_MFA_ID => params[:model]})
end
```

And such view:

```
- @manufacturers.each do |manufacturer|
    %li      
      = link_to manufacturer.MFA_BRAND, :controller => "types", :method => "model", :model => "111"
```

But how can I using link to send params to method "model"? For example: localhost/types/model/111
? So that rails server work normal? (now it gives me that i hav'nt such route)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this if you need to retain your methods to your routes.

```
match "/types/model/:model" => "types#model"
```

Comment: My type-controller have three methods: manufacturer, model, type. According to logic, manufacturer has many models, and model has many types. Is it better to write this methods in one controller, or to do 3 controllers one method in each?

Comment: If you are free to code.. then you should have 3 controllers - manufacturers_controller, models_controller and types_controller. Also, please consider renaming types and models to say vehicle_types and vehicle_models. It is very confusing with the Rails types and models definitions..

Answer (score 4):

Consider naming the model method 'show' and the URL will be /types/111. That would make your code RESTful

Comment: ...and it would also make it follow the Rails conventions, which will save you a lot of trouble down the road, unless you have a very good reason to create a custom-named action beyond the standards: index, show, new, create, edit, update, and destroy.

Comment: i have a reason for that, url can be types/model?blablabla, or another, just how to get to the method!

Comment: My type-controller have three methods: manufacturer, model, type. According to logic, manufacturer has many models, and model has many types. Is it better to write this methods in one controller, or to do 3 controllers one method in each?

Comment: according to your answer, i need scaffolds, and there routing... becouse i also will need route! you didn't answer on that theme

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities, the most important is to keep your application in a RESTful clean model (it will save you a lot of time).

First, you should really defines you model properly :

- Do you consider that one type as different models ?
- Do you consider that models is under the tye "directory" ?
- Do you consider that model is a function of a type object ?
- Do you consider that model is a global function of the type object ?

### Model as nested resource of type

In this case, you consider that a type instance has several models instances (like a company can have users). So you should have two restful controllers : one for model and one for type.

You can define such routes like this :

```
resources :types do
   resources :models
end
```

Your RESTful methods in the model controller will be called when going to **/types/14/model/1** with type_id of 14 and id of 1.

Regarding your question, I think it is the cleanest way.

### Model in types namespace

In this case, the model methods will be included in the types namespace but the controller is for handling model objects only.

```
namespace :types do
  resources :models
end
```

It will allow you to call **/types/models/1** to call the show function of the model controller.

### Model method as a method of a type instance

In this case, the model method is a function of a type instance :

```
resources :types do
   member do
      :model
   end
end
```

The method function of the type controller will be called when requesting **/types/42/model** with id = 42

### Model method as a global method for types

In this case, the model method is a global method for the global type class

```
resources :types do
   collection do
      :model
   end
end
```

In this case, the model method of the types controller will be called when **/types/model** is requested.

All is explained [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: My type-controller have three methods: manufacturer, model, type. According to logic, manufacturer has many models, and model has many types. Is it better to write this methods in one controller, or to do 3 controllers one method in each?

Comment: If the logic already links manufacturer, models and types, perhaps the best way would be two have three separated controllers only described as different resources. (/manufacturers/42, /models/42, /types/42)